# T-Sql: check if IP matches netmask

Tags: t-sql, ip-address, bit-manipulation, netmask

My SQL-Server db stores IP netmasks as binary.
I need a way to match these with a given IP

For example,
is `192.168.21.5` part of a netmask which is stored in the DB?

The binary representation of `192.168.21.5`:

```
11000000.10101000.00010101.00000101 (without the dots)
```

The netmask stored in the DB is: binary(4) and a tinyint field:

```
11000000.10101000.00010101.00000000 / 24
```

(which would be: `192.168.21.0 /24`) so, the first 24 bits of `192.168.21.5` have to match a record in the database.

How would I only check the first `n` bits of a binary field (similar to `LEFT(text, 24)`)?

Is there any clever way to do this, maybe with bitwise `AND`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
declare @address binary(4) -- goal is to check if this address
declare @network binary(4) -- is in this network
declare @netmask tinyint   -- with this netmask in /NN format

set @address = 0xC0A81505 -- 192.168.21.5
set @network = 0xC0A81500 -- 192.168.21.0
set @netmask = 24

select
  'address matches network/netmask'
where
  0 = (
      cast(@address as int) ^ cast(@network as int))
      &
      ~(power(2, 32 - @netmask) - 1)
      )
```

`@netmask` must be between 2 and 32.

Answer (score 1):

`192.168.21.5 XOR netmask (192.168.21.0) AND 255.255.255.0` (you want only first 24 bits) should be all `0` on the "matching" IP.

Answer (score 0):

This condition does it:

```
(0xffffffff - POWER(2, 32 - bits) + 1) & CAST(ip AS int) = CAST(netmask AS int)
```

Comment: is this meant only to work with bits>=24 (Class C Netmask) ?
could make it work, but not with say bits=16 (Class B)
but works with bits > 24 for smaller networks

Comment: Just checked it, and it seems to work for me for any number of bits. What problems are you getting for class B masks?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it work with mask 0 or 1 bit then you need change power(2, 32 - @netmask) to 
power(cast(2 as bigint), 32 - @netmask)
Bye